# Email sent from an account get saved and get identity from an other account

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I have 4 differents email accounts set up in thunderbird:

- Account A: with mail provider 1
- Account B: with mail provider 2
- Account C: gmail server
- Accound D: with mail provider 1

When I sent email from account D three things happen

1. When people received the email, the sender email is my gmail account
   (Account C)
2. The message is saved in my Account D sent folder
3. The message is saved in my Account C (gmail) sent folder

Please note that:

- All my account are IMAP server.
- Account A and D are hosted on the same email provider (ovh)
- This only happen with account D (account A and B works fine and email are saved in the right place, reply to is set properly)

My settings for Account A and D looks exactly the same. I don't understand why Thunderbird behave this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account D is probably mistakenly set to use Gmail as SMTP.

Check your Account Settings. If you click the account name (i.e. "Account D") in the left-hand pane of the Account Settings window, you'll see Account Name, Your Name, Email Address, etc.... at the very bottom, what does it say for "Outgoing Server (SMTP)"?

If it's not clear from the description of the server there, you can check under the "Outgoing Server" section in the left-hand pane.

If Account D is set to use Gmail's SMTP service, that would explain (1) why the sender appears as Gmail to recipients, and also (3) why the message is saved in your Gmail folder (Gmail is different that standard email services here, in that it will automatically save a copy of an email in your saved folder simply if you use Gmail SMTP -- doesn't matter what your mail client settings are).

Then, (2) the copy that also appears in your Account D folder is probably due to the "Copies & Folder" settings on your account. That's probably set to save the message under your Account D sent folder, yet because Account D is configured to route mail through Gmail's SMTP, Gmail saves a copy on its own too. (Any other SMTP server would leave storage of sent mail to the mail client, so Thunderbird is just doing as it's configured while Gmail keeps a copy anyways.)

Check the outgoing server... Account D should be using an SMTP server from the Account D provider, but my guess is that it's using a Gmail SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks, my outgoing Server was set to default which should be the gmail one.